# Send an address in a sms to map app

Tags: messages, sms, google-maps, mapping

If a friend sends to me an address in a SMS or IMessage, for example "I am at 123 Main St" can I send that to the Map app to get directions there?

Answer (score 2):

The iOS will hyperlink things such as addresses, and phone numbers, in things such as emails. If it doesn't do that, it is simple to tap and hold the address, copy it, and paste it into maps.